# Comprobar si ya existe empleado

Tags: java, netbeans, oracle-sqldeveloper

Estoy insertando datos en una tabla en una base de datos oracle sqldeveloper y quiero comprobar algunas cosas como (que ya exista el número del empleado o que no se introduzca correctamente, que el jefe no exista, que el salario >0, y que no exista el código de departamento) entre otras pero no se como comprobar lo que haya introducido el usuario con lo que hay en la tabla antes de introducir esos datos.
este es mi código para introducir los datos:

```
int emp_no, dir, dept_no;
    float salario, comision;
    String apellido, oficio, fecha;

    String insertEmployee = "INSERT INTO EMPLEADOS (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement pstmt1 = con.prepareStatement(insertEmployee);

    System.out.println("Indica el numero de treballador: ");
    emp_no = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Indica el cognom del treballador: ");
    keyboard.nextLine();
    apellido = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Indica l'ofici del treballador: ");
    oficio = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Indica el numero del director del treballador: ");
    dir = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Indica el dia quan es va contractar el treballador: ");
    keyboard.nextLine();
    fecha = keyboard.nextLine();
    sdf.parse(fecha);
    System.out.println("Indica el salari del treballador: ");
    salario = keyboard.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("Indica la comissio del treballador: ");
    comision = keyboard.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("Indica el numero de departament al que pertany el treballador: ");
    dept_no = keyboard.nextInt();

    pstmt1.setInt(1, emp_no);
    pstmt1.setString(2, apellido);
    pstmt1.setString(3, oficio);
    pstmt1.setInt(4, dir);
    pstmt1.setString(5, fecha);
    pstmt1.setFloat(6, salario);
    pstmt1.setFloat(7, comision);
    pstmt1.setInt(8, dept_no);

    pstmt1.executeUpdate();
    con.commit();}
```

Comment: Usa un trigger en oracle que compruebe si existe el empleado antes de insertarlo

Comment: puedo hacer eso des de el java? la idea es hacerlo todo des de allí

Comment: Entonces tienes que intentar otra forma. Te diría de hacer una SELECT antes del INSERT. En esa SELECT vas a meter en el WHERE los datos que has introducido por consola (aunque solo con el emp_no debería servirte). Si te devuelve algún resultado es que ya existe ese trabajador y no haces el INSERT, en caso contrario, inserta el trabajador.

Comment: he usado 'ResultSet resultado = statement.executeQuery("SELECT EMP_NO FROM EMPLEADOS WHERE EMP_NO = " + emp_no);' para comprobar si existe pero me salta sql exception porque no hay lectura de datos y peta el programa

Comment: Lo más fácil sería hacer algo equivalente al 'on duplicate key' de mysql, aquí tienes un ejemplo [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589350/oracle-db-equivalent-of-on-duplicate-key-update], espero que te sirva.

Comment: pero esto es para hacerlo en el sqldeveloper no des de java no?

Comment: Eso puedes hacerlo desde ambos sitios. Aparte si la select te da sql exception es o porque la tienes mal o porque tu base de datos tiene problemas.

Comment: la misma consulta des de el sqldeveloper me devuelve empleado si existe

Comment: La forma correcta es mediante la SELECT. Pon el código que has probado y la información del error en la pregunta, que es probablemente lo que se pueda arreglar. Edita la pregunta para modificarla, no pongas la información como comentarios.

Comment: he conseguido resolverlo publico la respuesta por separado o en la misma pregunta?

Comment: Por separado, para eso es una respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Al final con los consejos de todos he conseguido resolverlo con una sentencia y seguido usando resultset.next() ya que si encontraba el numero de empleado saltaría el resultset.next() he usado un boolean para indicar si podía o no añadir el usuario.

```
int emp_no, dir, dept_no;
    float salario, comision;
    String apellido, oficio, fecha;

    String insertEmployee = "INSERT INTO EMPLEADOS values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement pstmt1 = con.prepareStatement(insertEmployee);

    System.out.println("Indica el numero de treballador: ");
    emp_no = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Indica el cognom del treballador: ");
    keyboard.nextLine();
    apellido = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Indica l'ofici del treballador: ");
    oficio = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Indica el numero del director del treballador: ");
    dir = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Indica el dia quan es va contractar el treballador: ");
    keyboard.nextLine();
    fecha = keyboard.nextLine();
    sdf.parse(fecha);
    System.out.println("Indica el salari del treballador: ");
    salario = keyboard.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("Indica la comissio del treballador: ");
    comision = keyboard.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("Indica el numero de departament al que pertany el treballador: ");
    dept_no = keyboard.nextInt();
    Statement statement = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet checkEmp = statement.executeQuery("SELECT EMP_NO FROM EMPLEADOS WHERE EMP_NO = " + emp_no);
    boolean b = false; 
    while(checkEmp.next()){
        b= true;
    }
    if(b == false){
    pstmt1.setInt(1, emp_no);         
    pstmt1.setString(2, apellido);
    pstmt1.setString(3, oficio);
    pstmt1.setInt(4, dir);
    pstmt1.setString(5, fecha);
    pstmt1.setFloat(6, salario);
    pstmt1.setFloat(7, comision);
    pstmt1.setInt(8, dept_no);
    pstmt1.executeUpdate();
    con.commit();
    }else System.out.println("no s'ha pogut afegir el treballador");
```